# Добавить поле в form при помощи js

Tags: javascript, html, form, input

Есть веб страница, на ней есть form с двумя input(логин и пароль) и button. При нажатии на button на сервер передается значение двух input.
Нужно передавать на сервер логин и пароль, а также еще одно поле вычисляемое на веб странице (вычисляется при загрузки веб страницы).
Возможно ли добавить еще одно поле в form без зпоявления без появления новых тегов и отображения чего либо на веб странице при помощи js?
Хотелось бы сделать просто. Инициировал объект(или на чистом js или jQuery) и добавил поле при загрузке страницы.

Comment: переписывать не стану но посмотрите тут https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Comment: А без обработчика никак? Нехотелось бы дописывать целую функцию

Comment: Поймите если данных формы достаточно для вычисления значения то не делайте ничего на клиенте а вычисляйте его на сервере. Если не достаточно то у вас не получится добавить значение без JS

Comment: Данных недостаточно. Я хочу использовать js, возможно даже jquery. Но делать обработчик невариант.

Comment: Ну что сказать. Успехов

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
(function(){
  let myVar = 123456;
  let form = document.getElementById('frm');
  form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type="hidden" value="' + myVar + '" />');
})();
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm">
  <p><span>Login:</span><input type="text" name="login" /></p>
  <p><span>Password:</span><input type="password" name="pwd" /></p>
  <p><span></span><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
```

Либо, как Вам [предложил](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery) [Азиз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/387032), подпишитесь на событие отправки формы, попутно отменяя поведение формы по умолчанию и формируйте запрос к серверу программно.

Comment: В вашем варианте он не будет изменяться после занрузки формы.

Comment: @Aziz_Umarov а должен?

Comment: Не конечно, думаю не обязан про100 странно иметь переменную которую можно при загрузке страницы определить, но при этом не иметь ее после так что приходится отправлять  с формой

Comment: @AzizUmarov автор вопроса написал `поле вычисляемое на веб странице вычисляется при загрузки`. Я, как-бы, из этого и исходил. Как вычисляется поле, и другие детали были опущены в вопросе, поэтому в примере и была взята переменная с обычным статическим значением. И почему требуемое скрытое поле нельзя сразу добавить в разметку - тоже вопрос. В любом случае автор пропал и дополнительных деталей мы, скорее всего, не дождёмся.

Comment: Ясно вопросов нет, я думаю автор не имел это буквально.